# Android doInBackground error

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in android development and I get an error that I can not solve a few days ago with the `doInBackground()` method.
My error is at the end of my code, at

```
e2 = e11;
createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord = null;
this.sender = e2.getMessage();
createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
```

The error is

> Unhandled exception:java.io.IO.EXCEPTION

If you have solutions , thank you in advance!
My code :

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objArr) {
    BluetoothSocket createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord;
    IOException e;
    Throwable th;
    IButton a;
    Boolean valueOf;
    boolean z = true;
    this.jobType = (JobType) objArr[0];
    this.sender = (MainActivity) objArr[1];
    this.device = (BluetoothDevice) objArr[2];
    try {
        createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord =
                device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        try {
            createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.connect();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            Log.e("Bluetooth", e2.getMessage());
            Log.e("Bluetooth", "trying fallback");
            try {
                createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord = (BluetoothSocket)
                        this.device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[]{Integer.TYPE}).invoke(this.device, new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(1)});
            } catch (Exception e3) {
                Log.e("Bluetooth", e3.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.connect();
            } catch (IOException e4) {
                e2 = e4;
                try {
                    this.error = e2.getMessage();
                    try {
                        createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
                    } catch (IOException e5) {
                    }
                    return null;
                } catch (Throwable th2) {
                    th = th2;
                    try {
                        createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
                    } catch (IOException e6) {
                    }
                    throw th;
                }
            }
        }
        if (this.jobType == JobType.read) {
            a = readDevice(createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord);
            try {
                createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
                return a;
            } catch (IOException e7) {
                return a;
            }
        } else

        if (this.jobType == JobType.stopMission) {
            a = (IButton) objArr[3];
            if (!(stopMission(createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord) &&
                    writeDevice(createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord, a))) {
                z = false;
            }
            valueOf = Boolean.valueOf(z);
            try {
                createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
                return valueOf;
            } catch (IOException e8) {
                return valueOf;
            }
        } else

        if (this.jobType == JobType.startMission) {
            boolean z2 = writeDevice(createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord, (IButton) objArr[3]) &&
                    startMission(createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord);
            valueOf = Boolean.valueOf(z2);
            try {
                createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
                return valueOf;
            } catch (IOException e9) {
                return valueOf;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
            } catch (IOException e10) {
            }
            return null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e11) {
        e2 = e11;
        createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord = null;
        this.sender = e2.getMessage();
        createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
        return null;
    } catch (Throwable th3) {
        th = th3;
        createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord = null;
        createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
        throw th;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You should consider using `finally` for cleanups.

Answer (score 0):

[`close()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#close%28%29) also throws an `IOException` exception you need to handle. Additionally you should use a `finally` block for cleaning up and be careful not to provoke `NullPointerExeption`s by setting the variable to `null` before closing it.

You could improve your code like

```
try {
    ....
} catch (Exception e) {
    ....
} finally {
    try {
        createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
        createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Tynn , May thank's for your solution ! working perfect !

Answer (score 0):

I'm modify my code with this but i'm a java.lang.NullPointerException...
The fonction doInBackground() is very difficult...
Thank's for your help !

My code modify

```
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objArr) {
    BluetoothSocket createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord = null;
    IOException e;
    Throwable th;
    IButton a;
    Boolean valueOf;
    boolean z = true;
    this.jobType = (JobType) objArr[0];
    this.sender = (MainActivity) objArr[1];
    this.device = (BluetoothDevice) objArr[2];
    try {
        createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord =
                device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        try {
            createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.connect();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            Log.e("Bluetooth", e2.getMessage());
            Log.e("Bluetooth", "trying fallback");
            try {
                createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord = (BluetoothSocket)
                        this.device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[]{Integer.TYPE}).invoke(this.device, new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(1)});
            } catch (Exception e3) {
                Log.e("Bluetooth", e3.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.connect();
            } catch (IOException e4) {
                e2 = e4;
                try {
                    this.error = e2.getMessage();
                    try {
                        createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
                    } catch (IOException e5) {
                    }
                    return null;
                } catch (Throwable th2) {
                    th = th2;
                    try {
                        createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
                    } catch (IOException e6) {
                    }
                    throw th;
                }
            }
        }
        if (this.jobType == JobType.read) {
            a = readDevice(createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord);
            try {
                createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
                return a;
            } catch (IOException e7) {
                return a;
            }
        } else if (this.jobType == JobType.stopMission) {
            a = (IButton) objArr[3];
            if (!(stopMission(createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord) &&
                    writeDevice(createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord, a))) {
                z = false;
            }
            valueOf = Boolean.valueOf(z);
            try {
                createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
                return valueOf;
            } catch (IOException e8) {
                return valueOf;
            }
        } else if (this.jobType == JobType.startMission) {
            boolean z2 = writeDevice(createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord, (IButton) objArr[3]) &&
                    startMission(createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord);
            valueOf = Boolean.valueOf(z2);
            try {
                createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
                return valueOf;
            } catch (IOException e9) {
                return valueOf;
            }
        } else {
            try {
                createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
            } catch (IOException e10) {
            }
            return null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e11) {
        try {
            createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord = null;
        return null;
    } catch (Throwable th3) {
        th = th3;
    } finally {
        try {
            createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord.close();
            createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord = null;
        } catch (IOException e2) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is this your working example or another question? I'm not sure how to understand.

Comment: This is my working example, but no working... I'm a java.lang.NullPointerException error.

Comment: Then you should consider asking a new question. Or better look for the error yourself. `NullPointerExceptions` are easy to find. And at least a stacktrace from logcat is needed there.